# Как достать данные из списка словаря

Tags: python

у меня есть список

```
 res = [{1:{
                1: [ReservationData.Seat(id_coach=1, id_spot=1, text_from="0", text_to="5", text_special = 1)],
                2: [ReservationData.Seat(id_coach=1, id_spot=2, text_from="0", text_to="6", text_special = 2)],
                3: [ReservationData.Seat(id_coach=1, id_spot=3, text_from="0", text_to="11", text_special = 3)],
                4: [ReservationData.Seat(id_coach=1, id_spot=4, text_from="0", text_to="11", text_special = 4)],
                }}]
```

Мне надо достать данные второго словаря с ключом 1 и значением ReservationData то есть значение ключа 1 которые в квадратных скобках

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res = [
      ^ список, первый элемент списка берём как [0]
       {1:
       ^ словарь, берём значение по ключу, т.е. [1]
          {1: 
          ^ опять словарь, опять по ключу [1]
             [ReservationData...
             ^ список, первый элемент списка берём как [0]
```

Итого:

```
res[0][1][1][0]
```

Comment: ошибка `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: А он и содержит объект. Реализуйте у него функцию ``__str__`` и получите то, что нужно.

Comment: @Eklatov Ошибку нужно приводить вместе с кодом, к которому относится ошибка. Явно ошибка где-то уже в другом месте.

Comment: стр уже написано